# Not able to serialize the Python 2 objects from Python 3x

Tags: python-3.x, google-app-engine, serialization, django-rest-framework, google-cloud-datastore

We need to upgrade our monolith GAE application to Python 3.7 runtime.

Currently we are serializing Python 2 objects and stored in the Datastore (Google App Engine NDB Client) and trying to retrieve them as Python 3 objects.

But, we aren't able to access the Datastore Objects from Python 3.7 runtime.

```
File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/fields.py", line 371, in bind
    (field_name, self.__class__.__name__, parent.__class__.__name__)
AssertionError: It is redundant to specify `source='name'` on field 'CharField' in serializer 'Serializer', because it is the same as the field name. Remove the `source` keyword argument.
```

API.py

```
class AppList(generics.GenericAPIView):
    queryset = App.all()
    serializer_class = AppSerializer
    ndb_class = App

    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    
          queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())
          page = self.paginate_queryset(queryset)
          if page is not None:
               self.get_related_data(page)
               serializer = self.get_serializer(page, many=True)
               return self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)

          serializer = self.get_serializer(queryset, many=True)
          results = {'results': serializer.data}
          return Response(results)
```

In requirements.txt

```
Django==1.11.28
djangorestframework==3.9.4
django-csp==3.7
django-rest-swagger==2.2.0
```

Could someone please assist me?

Want to read/write the datastore objects that are stored in Python 27 from Python 37?

Comment: Include code snippet showing what you're doing

Comment: Added the Views and requirements.txt

Answer (score 0):

You are likely using `pickle` to store Python objects and the format is different for Python 2 and 3.

You'll need to convert your Python2 pickles to Python3 pickles, or better, store them as `json` or something else that is language independent.